# How to install new outdoor motion sensing light

Tags: lighting, installation, diy-vs-pro, light-fixture

I have a new home which does not have any sort of outdoor lights for now. I want to install motion sensing lights on 2 of the exterior walls. I got a quote from an electrical contractor but he is asking astronomical amount of money for running a PVC tube from an outdoor power port. I decided to do it on my own, but need some guidance as to how I can avoid the PVC pipe thing and wire it from internal walls and etc. Is there any guide I can use or anyone of you folks can guide me?

Let me know,
Thanks,
RV.

Comment: Is your house 1 story or 2?

Comment: Its a 2 story new build.

Comment: Do you have a basement?

Comment: Nope. I live in AZ and basements are very hard to find here in any of the homes. But to answer your question, no basement.

Comment: How comfortable are you with electrical work?  Do you have the tools and knowledge to do electrical work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From complex to simple, some options include:

- Run a new circuit from the panel to a new fixture box mounted on the outside of the house. This will require fishing lines through walls or crawlspaces or attics and drilling holes and installing junction boxes.
- find a junction box on the opposite side of the wall you want to mount the outside fixture. If you have a light switch on a wall on the inside of your house, you can replace that box with a larger one, running a short branch up the wall to the outside. Essentially the same as option 1, but easier.
- buy one of these LED battery powered spotlights. Requires no wiring:

[image]

You can buy those at any big-box store and I find them surprisingly decent solutions. Yes, you need to replace the batteries every so often, but it's so much easier to get them installed. Plus, I can attach them to trees (which helps in the PNW) :)

Comment: Point # 2 is what I am most willing to do. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate a junction box somewhere in the attic that has a hot wire (not a switch leg) and a neutral in it. Look close to an existing light fixture in a room close to where you want the exterior light(s). From there you can feed the motion-activated lights with NM cable (Romex) from the attic.

You can either cut boxes into the siding or mount surface boxes on the outside of the house. Whatever you feel comfortable with.

If the terminology is a bit confusing you should buy a book on basic wiring such as this one:
[http://www.amazon.com/Step-Guide-Book-Home-Wiring/dp/0961920106/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450304277&sr=8-1&keywords=Home+wiring+step+by+step](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961920106)

Not an endorsement just a suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have a power outlet on the inside wall of the home and this would be right behind the supposed point of the motion light. Can I drill right behind this interior light and feed the wire from there? Would that be any good?